# UIButton squeezed when project is run

Tags: ios, uibutton, interface-builder

I created a UIButton in interface builder, setting the size 81x31 and using an image of the same size. However, in the simulator it comes out looking very squeezed. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong? Also, I realize this is not a lot of information but I was not sure what was relevant. Please let me know if there's anything else I should post.

[image: in the simulator]

[image: in interface builder]

Comment: You probably did not set the device screen right in the simulator. You can choose between the retina modes under the hardware tab (or device tab)

Comment: the device is right (standard iphone)

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout? If so, please post the constraints of your button.

Comment: try [[myButton imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

Comment: @Yazid I had it constrained to another object that I had then moved. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.